# Shopify refunding an order response: "Arbitrary refund not allowed"

Tags: ruby, shopify-api

## Issue summary

We are refunding an order but the item being refunded has return shipping cost (*a variable we use on our side*), so we are subtracting that from the amount.
This is failing on a productive shop, but if we use test mode or bogus payment method the error wont appear and the refund will be created.
In the tests environments the refund is created with an `order_adjustment`. In the other hand when we try refunding in productive shops neither the refund nor the `order_adjustment` are created.

[Shopify shopify-api-ruby issue](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-ruby/issues/1232)

EXAMPLE:

```
return_shipping_cost_cents = 1 USD
maximum_refundable = 20 USD
amount = 19 USD
```

- `shopify_api` version: 21.4.1
- Ruby version: 3.0.6p216
- Operating system: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

### Expected behavior

Shopify should create the adjustment to the order and refund the amount.

### Actual behavior

The error message:  `{"errors"=>{"base"=>["Arbitrary refund not allowed"]}}`

### Steps to reproduce the problem

1. Get `order_id` and `line_item_id` from an order with a real payment (not a test mode payment)
2. Call to the `/orders/#{order_id}/refunds/calculate` endpoint (POST)
   Sample payload:

```
{
"refund_line_items"=>[
  {
    "line_item_id"=>"11922901111117",
    "quantity"=>1,
    "restock_type"=>"no_restock"
  }
],
"shipping"=>{
  "full_refund"=>false
}
}
```

3. Create a payload to be refunded with the amount (`amount - return_shipping_cost_cents`)
   Sample payload refunds endpoint:

```
return_shipping_cost_cents = 6,95
{
  "shipping": {
    "amount": "0.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "maximum_refundable": "0.00"
  },
  "duties": [],
  "total_duties_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "0.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "0.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "return": null,
  "refund_line_items":
  [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "line_item_id": 11922901111117,
      "location_id": null,
      "restock_type": "no_restock",
      "price": "62.97",
      "subtotal": "62.97",
      "total_tax": "4.25",
      "discounted_price": "62.97",
      "discounted_total_price": "62.97",
      "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
    }
  ],
  "transactions": 
  [
    {
      "order_id": 4786111111837,
      "kind": "refund",
      "gateway": "shopify_payments",
      "parent_id": 6017111111269,
      "amount": 60.27,
      "currency": "USD",
      "maximum_refundable": "67.22"
    }
  ],
  "currency": "USD",
  "note": "33HxxxYvLq"
}
```

4. Call `orders/#{order_id}/refunds`:
5. Response: `=> {"errors"=>{"base"=>["Arbitrary refund not allowed"]}}`

We are trying to refund an order charging the `return_shipping`, and we are expecting that [Shopify](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-ruby) creates the `refund` with an `order_adjustment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential thing that might be creating this error could be that the order has been payed out with a gateway that doesn't allow "partial refunds". Check the original gateway payment isn't one of:

- PayPal
- Facebook
- Instagram (kind of part Facebook)

Comment: Yes, according to Shopify support this is a restriction from FB side. Refunding an order from FB must be refunded with the original amount.